# Rotating an interval about the origin?

Tags: calculus

> ***Question:*** Working in the $(x,y)$ plane I write an interval on the $x-$axis, $I=[n-1,n].$ How do I construct an integral to compute
>   the area by rotating $I$ about the origin $(0,0) ?$ Rotating $I$
>   results in an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_(mathematics).) I am interested in the construction of the integral not in the explicit formula for the area of the annulus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating the interval by the angle $\theta_0$ yields the following integral

$$\int_0^{\theta_0} \int_{n-1}^n r\,dr\,d\theta = \int_0^{\theta_0} \frac{n^2 - (n-1)^2}{2}\,d\theta = \int_0^{\theta_0} \frac{2n-1}{2}\,d\theta = \frac{2n-1}{2}\theta_0$$

The distance from the origin $r$ is within the interval $I = [n-1, n]$. The $r$ in the integral comes from computing the area integral in poolar coordinates.

Comment: Can we illustrate this with an example: say $\theta_0=180$ ?

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez Well, just plug in $\theta_0 = \pi$ (in radians) and calculate the integral $$\int_0^{\pi} \int_{n-1}^n r\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{2n-1}2\pi$$.

Comment: Where is the symmetry in the integral ? For example if $I=[n,n+1]$ ? I am asking as a comment here - it is not worth a separate question on MSE.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez You would again have $r \in I = [n, n+1]$ so the integral is $$\int_0^{\theta_0} \int_{n}^{n+1} r\,dr\,d\theta = \frac{2n+1}2\theta_0$$

Answer (score 0):

That annulus is centered at the origin, its inner radius is $n-1$ and its outer radius is $n$. Therefore, the integral that you are looking for is$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{n-1}^nr\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=2\pi\int_{n-1}^nr\,\mathrm dr,$$since the area element in polar coordinates is $r$.

Answer (score 0):

If you use polar coordinates, your integral is simply
$$I=\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta\int_{n-1}^n \rho d\rho$$
where $\rho$ is the absolute value of Jacobian determinant.

Comment: How do you integrate by the absolute value of the Jacobian?